# scipy.optimize.minimize -- how to specify bounds when one is a numpy array

Tags: python

I am running an optimization with scipy.optimize.minimize

```
sig_init = 2
b_init = np.array([0.2,0.01,0.5,-0.02])
params_init = np.array([b_init, sig_init])
mle_args = (y,x)
results = opt.minimize(crit, params_init, args=(mle_args))
```

The problem is, I need to set a bound on `sig_init`. But the `opt.minimize()` requires that I specify bounds for each of the input parameters. But one of my inputs is a numpy array.

How can I specify the bounds given that one of my inputs is a numpy array?

Comment: What is the definition of `crit`?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, scipy.optimize.minimize expects a flat array as its second argument x0 ([documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize)) (which means the function it optimizes also takes a flat array and optional additional arguments). Therefore it is my understanding you would have to give it something like :

```
 b_init = [0.2,0.01,0.5,-0.02]
 sig_init = [2]
 params_init = np.array(b_init + sig_init])
```

for the optimization to work.
Then, if you will have to give the bounds for each scalar in you array. One rudimentary example if you wanted [-1, 1] bounds on sig and didn't want bounds on b :

```
bounds = [(-np.inf, np.inf) for _ in b_init] + [(-1, 1)]
```